# First time Installation - No partition can be seen

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I want to install Ubuntu alongside with Windows 8.1 that I have. Earlier, my windows corrupted so I had a full fresh installation. I dont know anything about MBR or GPT. 
I am installing Ubuntu 14 and when selecting "something else", its showing my harddrive without any partition. I want to install Ubuntu on a partition.
I am new. I dont know what is FixParts or things like these. 
Please help, step by step.

Regards,

Comment: possible duplicate of [This computer currently has no detected operating systems (no UEFI)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/592266/this-computer-currently-has-no-detected-operating-systems-no-uefi)